# Is the accuracy the best metrics to evaluate the performance of Deep Learning model?

Tags: deep-learning, performance, accuracy

Consider a model `A` that achieved an test accuracy of 99% on dataset-A with the size of 200 images and a model `B` that achieved only 50% on dataset-B with a size of 50,000 images. Also consider both the datasets split into train,validation and test sets in the ratio of 0.8,0.1,0.1.

But on test data of dataset-B,the model A is failed to attain same accuracy in fact it is giving lesser accuracy that of model B.

So, is the accuracy always the best measure to evaluate the performance of the DL model? Or any other better performance metrics available?

Comment: What do you mean by "But in real real-time, model B is more robust than model A."? Do you mean that when you use B to predict on the real data B has better accuracy than A? What do you mean by "more robust" here?

Answer (score 1):

No, accuracy is not by far the best or the only measure you should look. It is not universal, accuracy only applies for classification problems, if you do regression then accuracy cannot be used.

There are a lot of metrics that can be used to monitor learning and predictive performance of models, there are too many to mention here. But the very important point, is that you should select metrics according to the problem and the desired behavior for the model, there is no best for this exact reason, since every problem is different.

It is very important to always think on the loss and metrics to be used for your model and problem, and not to take default choices.

Comment: Can you please give some use cases when to use loss as metrics over accuracy?

Answer (score 1):

I support what Dr. Snoopy said. Other metrics include AUC (area under the curve), precision, recall, sensitivity, specificity, positive predicted value, negative predicted value,...

It ultimately depends on the context that you are deploying your model, and what the best standards to judge by are in the field.